# Is it possible to host a vpn on a website server running on nginx?

Tags: nginx, vpn, openvpn, vps

I have a vps with one ip address and I am running a website with a domain on it through nginx. Now I want to use the same vps as a personal vpn while having my website up and running.
How can I achieve this? Is this possible? Is another ip address required?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

HTTP servers use port 80 for http, and 443 for https. None of these ports is required for VPN. Which port VPN's default to depends on the solution, and for many of the solutions, it can be freely changed and distributed together with the rest of the configuration.